xwininfo: what is "depth"?
The very useful xwininfo outputs information like this:
  Absolute upper-left X:  1261
  Absolute upper-left Y:  53
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  0
  Width: 1252
  Height: 2320
  Depth: 32
  Visual: 0x2d8
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x3e000af (not installed)
  Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: no
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: no
  Corners:  +1261+53  -1327+53  -1327-27  +1261-27
  -geometry 1252x2320+1256+0

My question: what is the depth parameter? is it colour depth? the man xwininfo page doesn't say.
Thank you!

Yes, depth denotes the colour depth in "bits per pixel". See the manual.

Thank you. I checked man xwininfo first, but it actually doesn't say what depth is.
